# not displaying all the elements of objects in an array validation, only showing last variable of the element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects -- table with rows (each row is an object)

Trying to validate the array of objects. Doesn't show any error message if i have an error in the middle row. If i have an error in the last row, it displays. Please help me out.

I tried for loop :

```
for (i=0, i<schoolarray.length; i++) {
    if (schoolarray[i]['school name'] = "") {
       alert('school name is empty');
    }
    else if (schoolarray[i]['school name'] != "") {
        alert('school name is not empty');
    }
   if (schoolarray[i]['school street'] = "") {
       alert('school street is empty');
    }
    else if (schoolarray[i]['school street'] != "") {
        alert('school street is not empty');
    }
    if (schoolarray[i]['school add'] = "") {
       alert('school addis empty');
    }
    else if (schoolarray[i]['school add'] != "") {
        alert('school add is not empty');
    }
}
```

error messages displayed not properly... different iteration gets different element message!

Tried foreach loop below : 
similar problem : Anyone suggest me?

schoolarray = [ {
        school name: "first school",
        school street: "first street",
        school add : "first add"
        },
        {
        school name: "second school",
        school street: "second street",
        school add : "second add"
        },
        {
        school name: "third school",
        school street: "third street",
        school add : "third add"
        }
        ]

```
  if (schoolarray.length > 0 ) {

    schoolarray.forEach(function(schoolObject, index) {
        console.log(schoolObject['school name']);

         Object.keys(schoolObject).forEach(function(prop) {    
            if(schoolObject['school name'] == "" ) {
            alert('enter school');
            }
            else if (schoolObject['school name'] != "" ) {
                alert('good');
            }   
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `for loop` is incorrect. There is no need of multiple `if` `elseif`. You need to only check if the prop `school name` is empty or not.

In your `forEach` loop, you already have an school object, there is no need of `Object.keys`.

```js
const schoolarray = [{
    "school name": "first school",
    "school street": "first street",
    "school add": "first add"
  }, {
    // Empty
    "school name" : "",
    "school street" : "second street",
    "school add" : "second add"
  }, {
    "school name" : "third school",
    "school street" : "third street",
    "school add" : "third add"
  }];

if (schoolarray.length > 0 ) {
    schoolarray.forEach(function(schoolObject, index) {
        if(!schoolObject['school name']) {
            console.log('Please enter school name', schoolObject);
        } else {
            console.log('School name is not empty: ', schoolObject['school name']);    
        }
    });
}
```

Using `for loop`

```js
const schoolarray = [{
    "school name": "first school",
    "school street": "first street",
    "school add": "first add"
  }, {
    "school name" : "",
    "school street" : "second street",
    "school add" : "second add"
  }, {
    "school name" : "third school",
    "school street" : "third street",
    "school add" : "third add"
  }];

for (i=0; i<schoolarray.length; i++) {
    if(!schoolarray[i]["school name"]) {
        console.log('Please enter school name', schoolarray[i]);
    } else {
        console.log('School name is not empty: ', schoolarray[i]["school name"]);  
    }
}
```

PS: Don't use `alert` as it will block the window repaint.